# flutter bloc: variable is not defined in BlocBuilder

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am trying to use Flutter bloc in my project.After creating State and Event class in State i have a `LanguageLoad` class:

```
abstract class LanguageState extends Equatable {
  const LanguageState();
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class LanguageInitial extends LanguageState {}

class LanguageLoad extends LanguageState {
  final Locale locale;
  LanguageLoad(this.locale);
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [locale];
}
```

After creating bloc class i am using in main class:

```
    void main() {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      runApp(
        BlocProvider(
            create: (_) => LanguageBloc()..add(LanguageLoadStarted()),
            child: MyApp()),
      );
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<LanguageBloc, LanguageState>(
      builder: (context, languageState) => MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        locale: languageState.locale, // locale is not defined
}
```

But I don't know why locale is not defined in `locale: languageState.locale` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't know the type of `languageState` and you need to cast it to obtain `locale` value. This is a piece of my in production app:

```
BlocBuilder<LanguageBloc, LanguageState>(
    builder: (context, state) {
      Locale locale;
      if (state is LanguageLoaded) {
        locale = state.locale;
      }
      return MaterialApp(
        locale: locale,
```

In my case I load `MaterialApp` even if Locale first time is null. It depends by you app logic.